# Height of linearlayout in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a problem with my linear layouts. 
There is two linear layout vertical in a horizontal parents, the first one dont take the same height of the second.

There is my LinearLayout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nomPers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nom User"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateVisite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Type de visite"
            android:id="@+id/typeVisteCli"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/tv_list_obs_visite_cli"
            android:text="obs"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And a screen of what i have :

[image]

You can see that the gray dont fill the entire linearLayout. 
Thx.

---

EDIT

I'm really sorry i put the wrong LinearLayout ...

Comment: The same code is working perfectly, so there might be some problem with how you implement it in the recyclerview, so can you please share that code as well?

Comment: @KaranMehta i just realize that i have put the wrong linearLayout, i have edited the post, so sorry

Comment: Hi @Neokerd i see some answers posted, If you don't see them working let me know i can help you out.

Comment: @Manikanta its ok now but i will come talk with u if i need help with android studio things :)

Comment: Hi @Manikanta pls can u come help me on this point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59842015/select-and-copy-text-in-a-textview-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nomPers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nom User"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateVisite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Type de visite"
            android:id="@+id/typeVisteCli"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/tv_list_obs_visite_cli"
            android:text="obs"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it works, can u tell me what u changed ? can't find

Comment: Yes, i changed wrap_content to match_parent in linear layout that has gray background color.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrote **wrap_content** in **second** linear layout height.You should change it with match_parent.

Comment: That won't help

Comment: If i do like this, the blue line will cut the text

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.I am changing your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_ti_cli"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nomPers_ti_cli"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Nom User"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Observation"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/tv_list_obs_ti_cli"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So sorry, ur answer make me realize that i've post the wrong linearlayout, thanks for ur answer